# Clearing Panel controls fail to call Form.Close (or) Form.Leave events

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

**What I have done**:
I have 3 `Forms`, in which I have panel in `Form_1` and 2 buttons (`button_1`, `button_2`).

`button_1` click event add the `Form_2` in panel. (before if I clear the `Panel` controls)
`button_2` click event add the `Form_3` in panel. (before if I clear the `Panel` controls)

**What I look for**:
In `Form_2` and `Form_3` i have `Form.closing()` and `Form.Leave()` event, but non of this function called.

I have opened Serial Port in `Form_2`, it fails to close properly.

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form_1 : Form
{
    public Form_1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_2 ObjForm_2 = new Form_2();
        panelBody.Controls.Clear();
        panelBody.Refresh();

        if (ObjForm_2.IsDisposed)
        {
            ObjForm_2 = new Form_2();
        }
        ObjForm_2.TopLevel = false;
        ObjForm_2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        ObjForm_2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelBody.Controls.Add(ObjForm_2);
        ObjForm_2.Show();
    }

    private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_3 ObjForm_3 = new Form_3();
        panelBody.Controls.Clear();
        panelBody.Refresh();

        if (ObjForm_3.IsDisposed)
        {
            ObjForm_3 = new Form_3();
        }
        ObjForm_3.TopLevel = false;
        ObjForm_3.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        ObjForm_3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelBody.Controls.Add(ObjForm_3);
        ObjForm_3.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Everytime you want clear the existing form and add the new one?

Comment: is the answer is helpful to clear out the issue? it's helped then mark as `Answer`.

Comment: Controls.Clear() is a very dangerous method with a name that is too misleading, it does not dispose the controls that are removed.  Instead they are re-hosted to the invisible "parking window", surviving forever.  You must instead use `while (panelBody.Controls.Count > 0) panelBody.Controls[0].Dispose()`

Comment: And be careful with SerialPort, it takes a while after calling its Close() or Dispose() method before the port can Open() again.  A worker thread needs to exit, how long that takes is unpredictable.  So you don't want it to be a member of your ObjForm_2 class.

Comment: @HansPassant, can I use Thread.Sleep(1000) after closing Serial Port. And even opening Serial Port also takes some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `Close` the form after clear the controls from the panel.

```
public partial class Form_1 : Form
{
    private Form frmChild;
    public Form_1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (frmChild != null)
        {
            frmChild.Close();
            frmChild.Dispose();
        }
        panelBody.Controls.Clear();

        frmChild = new Form_2();
        frmChild.TopLevel = false;
        frmChild.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frmChild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelBody.Controls.Add(frmChild);
        frmChild.Show();
    }

    private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelBody.Controls.Clear();

        if (frmChild != null)
        {
            frmChild.Close();
            frmChild.Dispose();
        }
        panelBody.Controls.Clear();

        frmChild = new Form_3();
        frmChild.TopLevel = false;
        frmChild.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frmChild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelBody.Controls.Add(frmChild);
        frmChild.Show();
    }
}
```

Thanks to `Jimi` the `frmChild.Dispose()` is moved to before the `panelBody.Controls.Clear()` for details check the comments

Comment: `frmChild.Close();` and `frmChild.Dispose()` before `panelBody.Controls.Clear();`. No `.Refresh()` required.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi. Why need to change the sequence? In fact, `Clear` method is not required at this context. Why because the control will be removed from the `Controlscollection` as soon as the control is `Disposed` from memory.

Comment: Those are two different things. Disposing an object is required to allow the garbage collection of a no more used reference (especially required since it's a Form). `Controls.Clear()` empties the underlying `ControlCollection` **and** it's cache. `Control.Clear()` is just a `while` loop with `.RemoveAt([Index])`. It does not `Dispose` anything. But it clears the `ArrangedElementCollection` (Layout related). .Net source code: [Control.ControlCollection.Clear()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,14995). Use both.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi and grateful to you. Yes, problem solved. Now Form.Close() event called where i can Close Serial Port.

Comment: Thanks @Baskar John. Form.Close(), Form.Dispose(), Control.Clear() -> This order works greatly. As Jimi said Refresh() is not needed.